# Android Studio emulator Error: MulltiDisplay.cpp

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having a problem with my android studio emulator.
Everything is working fine when i work on my phone as an emulator but whenever I open the virtual one I get the following errors in the event log with the following display
Event Log Error: Emulator: emulator: ERROR: MultiDisplay.cpp:114: Adb interface unavailable
. [Display Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj3zA.png)

[Event Log Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqECZ.png)